# How to make CSS property animation work in Safari as it does in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, cross-browser

I have a problem with CSS animation.

In my project I need to add `@keyframes` to style object and animation property to style of some DIVs by JavaScript.

```
<div class="a1" style="animation: d 3.2s linear infinite;">
  <div class="b1" style="animation: e 3.2s linear infinite;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the task: https://jsfiddle.net/gcfzf8q4/5/

This example works correctly in Google Chrome.

In Safari (after version 9) the green rectangle does not to move or it moves with a strange trajectory.

**Question**

How can I achieve the outcomes I get in Chrome in Safari?

Comment: have you tried to use the right keywords for safari : 

`@-webkit-keyframes anim_name {
                      // your animation ...
}`

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, it is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a strange Safari bug/inconsistency. I was able to get around this by setting the `div`'s animation styling via JavaScript instead of in the HTML. The key here is that you're telling the browser to check for the animation after it's been defined by making the `appendChild` calls.

```
// ... omitted some code for length, see jsfiddle in question ...

var style = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(style);
style.appendChild(rule1);
style.appendChild(rule2);

var a1 = document.getElementsByClassName("a1")[0];
var b1 = document.getElementsByClassName("b1")[0];
a1.style = "animation: d 3.2s linear infinite;";
b1.style = "animation: e 3.2s linear infinite;";
```